# Retain PHP script variables across multiple AJAX requests to that PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

How can I retain variables in PHP script across multiple AJAX calls to that PHP Script ? 
Would SESSION variable work if I start a session just at the beginning of the script? Or, would each SESSION be destroyed at the end of each AJAX request/script execution ?
Will it work if do not manually close the session at the end of the script ?

Comment: You really should start by reading the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php  Everything you've asked is explained there.

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: Have you considered putting the values into hidden fields, then passing those along via AJAX.  No chance of them expiring, no need for a session dependency.

Comment: I was under the impression that the session is closed when the server completes sending the response. How wrong was I!
Got it from the docs. However, I ended up using hidden form fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

SESSION should work. Sessions work by adding a unique cookie to the users browser. The session should be maintained as long as you are hitting your server from the same browser.

Comment: What if you hit the server from your mom's browser?